# Code folding in RStudio: Creating hierarchy in the code

Tags: ide, rstudio, folding

I'm writing R scripts in RStudio and I use the [code folding](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections) a lot. I found that you can see the hierarchy of the folding by pressing  <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +  <kbd>O</kbd>. This is super helpful.

```
# to my dear love ---------------------------------------------------------
2+2 
# yo man ====
x.2 = function (x) {x+2}

### I do love potatoes ####
```

See the result by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +  <kbd>O</kbd>.

[image]

I don't understand how this is working because when I write the code below, I can create a subsection without text but not when there is text in it (using `# ====` but not `# yo man ====`).

```
# to my dear love ---------------------------------------------------------
2+2
# ==== 

# yo man ====

### I do love potatoes ####
x.2 = function (x) {x+2}
data = "here is some data"
```

See the result by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +  <kbd>O</kbd>.
[image]

You can see that under `# to my dear love ---------------------------------------------------------` everything under is shifted to the right! This is cool!

1. The question is thus, how could it be possible to create a hierarchy of sections that include text in it?
2. Is it a peculiar package or Emac that is doing this? How can I create subsections, with text, and see the hierarchy in the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +  <kbd>O</kbd> box?
3. How can I down shift a section (going to a higher section (say section 2) to a lower section (section 1), by decreasing the visual hierarchy in the right box?

## EDIT

I wanted to add a comment on a simpler way of doing it now (which is similar to regular markdown (beside the `----` at the end); note that the maximum number of levels seems to be 6):

```
# Description -------------------------------------------------------------
### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
# Created by Me!
# Institution
# Created on DATE
# Why:
# Requires: 
# NOTES: 
### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###

# Abstract ----

# This is a comment 

# Introduction ----

## Important math ----
answer = 2 + 2 


# Material and methods ----

## Another function in the wall ----
cement = function(brick) {
  log(brick)
}
### Subsection 1.1 ----

#### Subsection 1.1.1 ----

##### Subsection 1.1.1.1 ----

###### Subsection 1.1.1.1.1 ----

####### Subsection 1.1.1.1.1.1 ----

# Results ----
answer
cement(exp(1))

# [...] ----
```

Gives

[image]

Comment: To create visual hierarchy (just for the benefit of the outline panel) I use uppercase for sections `# SECTION1 ----` and '.'+space lowercase by for subsections `# . Subsection1.1 ----`. It does not affect the folding but it creates a visual structure.

Comment: There is an open GitHub issue request to add support for subsections/subheadings in Rstudio.  To support this request, see here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4124

Comment: This is now available as of RStudio v1.4 https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/12/02/rstudio-v1-4-preview-little-things/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per Chris's answer [subheaders within functions](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/27499)

RStudio Code Folding hierarchy only works within function definitions and if-else structures.  For example:

```
# Section 1 ----
a <- 1

testfunct1 <- function () {
# sect in function=====
  b <- 2
  c <- 3
}

# Section 2 #####
d <- 4

# Section 3 =======
e <- 5

testfunct2 <- function () {
  # sect in function 2 =====
  f <- 6
  testsubfunct2_1 <- function () {
  # sect in subfunction 2_1 -----
    if (a == 1) {
      # section in if ----
      g < 7
    } else {
      # section in else ----
      h = 8
    }
  } 
}

# Section 4 ####
j <- 9
```

Produces this outline:

[image: Code Outline screenshot]

I don't know why the if-else section labels do not line up.

Answer (score 7):

Just discovered I could use various special characters across the top of my keyboard in combination with hyphens to produce a hierarchical look to the code section ToC. I chose the asterisk for this example, but you can use anything from the special character keys across the top to produce this look.

[image]