# How to make a hierarchical structure of folds/collapses in the text editor?

Tags: rstudio, folding

I want to format this:

```
# 1 =====
tibble()
## 1.1 ====
tibble()
### 1.1.1 ====
tibble()
# 2 =====
tibble()
## 2.1 ====
tibble()
### 2.1.1 ====
tibble()
```

If I collapse # 1 and # 2, I would like to get:

```
# 1 =====
# 2 =====
```

But instead I just get this:

```
# 1 =====
## 1.1 ====
tibble()
### 1.1.1 ====
tibble()
# 2 =====
## 2.1 ====
tibble()
### 2.1.1 ====
tibble()
```

Is it possible to have multiple "levels" of folding in rstudio?

My purpose is this: I have some long code with multiple folds inside and it has to be repeated 32 times. I would like to be able to fold all those 32 instances without losing the foldability of the inside contents of each of the 32 instances.

Comment: The IDE only provides one level of folding.

Comment: Thank you!, oh well that's how it is.

Comment: You can offer the suggestion to the posit people on their github issues page, but who knows how long it would take them to incorporate if they do.

Comment: Perhaps this is proving me wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837095/code-folding-in-rstudio-creating-hierarchy-in-the-code

Comment: I saw that question, but it just shows you the hierachy in the side, it doesn't create a "sub fold"

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if that was enough to cover your ask. I think the only avenue is to put in a feature request.